# OpenMp only one thread executes

Tags: c, openmp

I have set 4 threads.[Screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bItfP.png) But only one threads executes in parallel region (look at "id"). [Screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsSkx.png).
Available threads (I used omp_get_max_threads()).
What is wrong?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  int P = atoi(argv[1]);

omp_set_num_threads(4);
#pragma parallel for
  for( int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++ ) {
    printf("%d\n",omp_get_max_threads());
    printf("Num Threads:%d ",omp_get_num_threads());
    printf("id:%d\n",omp_get_thread_num());
  }
  while(1);
  const uint num_elements = 79;
  int* data = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * num_elements);
  for( uint i = 0; i < num_elements; i++ ) {
    data[i] = rand() % 100 - 50;
  }
  int* buffer = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * num_elements);
  PrintArray(data,0,num_elements);
  int* res = MergeSort(data,buffer,0,num_elements - 1,8);
  PrintArray(res,0,num_elements);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't include/link images; copy-paste the relevant code/output into your question.

Comment: How do you compile the code?

Comment: Haven't you forgot the `omp` flag in the `pragma` ? I think it should be this way : `#pragma omp parallel for`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was: #pragma parallel for.

Correct instruction is "#pragma omp parallel for"

Comment: I was so annoyed for a week then I realized that I wrote "#pragma omp parellel" instead of "#pragma omp parallel". That was obviously a novice mistake. Thank you mate.

Answer (score -1):

```
printf("%d\n",omp_get_max_threads());
printf("Num Threads:%d ",omp_get_num_threads());
printf("id:%d\n",omp_get_thread_num());
```

Please place these three printf into one printf. Easy. Then remove {}  the brackets from the for loop, 
and it works, I tested. It's just that I am writing here from my smartphone. I am going to add to github the basic for sample later.

Comment: This actually do not answer the question